# Lessening GPU processing power on MATLAB for plots

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a graph with a lot of points and I want to be able to look at certain intervals using `xlim`. The issue is, when I increment the interval, I have to rerun my program. This is taking a lot of processing power.

So basically, I make graph using `plot`, then use `xlim`. I don't want to keep doing this. Is there a way to plot only certain intervals using `plot`? That way, MATLAB doesn't have to process the whole vector.

---

For example

```
A=[1,2,3,4]
```

and

```
B=[1,2,3,4]
```

If I do `plot(A,B)` then `xlim(1,2)` it would plot the graph first and then limit the interval. This takes a lot of processing power if you imagine a really massive complicated graph, thus I don't want to use plot using the normal method.

Is there a way to plot the graph on the interval `x=[1,2]` with only  one function?

Comment: How about  ```plot(A(1:2), B(1:2))```?

Comment: Why do you have to rerun your program?  Save the vector you want, plot it, then use xlim and/or pan to move the view around.

Answer (score 1):

Update the `XLimMode` and `NextPlot` properties of your axes object before plotting. e.g.

```
x = randn(128,1); 
y = randn(128,1); 
hax = axes(); 
hax.XLimMode = 'manual'; 
hax.XLim = [1,2]; 
hax.NextPlot = 'add'; 
h = plot(x,y,'o','Parent',hax)
hax.NextPlot = 'replace'; % optional
```